# why this code gives me an exception invalid character

Tags: javascript, json

I have this web service that gets all the names of the city and returns json formatted string.

```
public  String  getDataForTowns( ) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{   
   String  strXml = "";

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            try 
            {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/plovdivbizloca", "postgres", "tan");
            }   

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Statement mystmt = null;
        String selectQuery = "select * from municipality_id";
        try {
            mystmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet mysr = mystmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = mysr.getMetaData();
            int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            int numberrow = 0;

            strXml += "{\"rows\": [";
            while (mysr.next()) 
            {               
                    String townname = mysr.getString(2);
                    String townid=mysr.getString(1);

                    strXml += "{\"town\":\"" + townname
                            + "\", \"id\":" + townid + "},";


                //strXml += ",";
            }
            strXml += "]}";
        } 

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        }

        return strXml;
    }
```

and on the client side I've got this function and on the alert statement it gives me exception "Invalid character".

```
function loadTownSelect()
    {
         select =  document.getElementById('sphSel');
         createXMLHttpRequest();

         var txtDrop = new Array();
         var idDrop= new Array();

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var xmlObj = xmlhttp.responseXML;   

                var textXML = xmlObj.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                alert(textXML);

                var nwresp = JSON.parse(textXML);
                alert (nwresp.rows[2].town);               
            }
        }

        var url = "http://localhost:9091/localbusscat/services/localbusscat/getDataForTowns";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    }
```

Comment: Does it tell you what the invalid character is and what line it's located on?

Comment: The invalid character most likely comes from `JSON.parse(textXML);`, it looks like you're probably ending your JSON string with `},]` i.e. a left over comma

Comment: You're using a variable called `strXml` to build a JSON formatted string?

Comment: You know there are libraries to create JSON for nearly any language? Chances are that you create invalid JSON when you build it manually.

Comment: @FelixKling There are many reasons why you may want to build one manually, though, e.g. code optimisation, cutting out extra steps, learning for yourself, portability/licencing/not wanting reliance on other projects, etc.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serverside code adds a comma after *every* "object literal", even the last one, which should not end at comma. This extra comma causes an error when parsing the string with `JSON.parse()` on clientside

```
+ "\", \"id\":" + townid + "},";
-----------------------------^
```